# SQLAlchemy/Python: Using an engine per process, and injecting that engine into dependencies

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, inversion-of-control, python-3.4

SQLAlchemy recommends using one engine per process because the underlying DBAPI connections are not necessarily safe to use across processes.

I have global `engine` and `session` variables that gets lazily populated with a SQLAlchemy engine and a session factory, respectively. This makes it easy to write database helpers that depend can call `get_session()` at runtime to use the `session` variable after it has been assigned a value by `init_db`.

That works well for letting helpers that need access to `engine` or `session` be imported before `engine` or `session` are initialized. But this pattern locks me into using one `engine` and `session` globally.

However, what I really need to do is:

```
engine, session = init_db(DB_URL)
```

... from the calling application/method, and then inject the session into these database helpers. Why? Well, I need to use one engine per process. I think I need an inversion of control pattern here, but am having trouble coming up with something workable (that doesn't involve passing the session around to the helpers on each call, which is hacky and a last resort).

I thought I could just set up the engine after `os.fork()`. Each process would start with `engine=None`, then instantiate it. But `engine` has the same memory address in both the parent and child process. This makes sense; it's how Python works.

```
from utils import init_db, engine, DB_URL
import os

def connect():
    print('before fork, engine is: {}'.format(id(engine)))
    newpid = os.fork()

    if newpid == 0:
        init_db(DB_URL)
        print('child engine is: {}'.format(id(engine))) # id(engine) is equal to below call
    else:
        init_db(DB_URL)
        print('parent engine is: {}'.format(id(engine))) # id(engine) is equal to above call

if __name__ == '__main__':
    connect()
```

Is my best option to create a pool of sorts based on the process ID? I'd like to use a clean inversion of control pattern if possible.

`NullPool` doesn't pool connections and would make this work, but I don't think that's a good thing - it seems expensive to constantly open and close connections?

Python version: 3.4.0

SQLAlchemy version: 0.9.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `id()` results are deceptive due to virtual memory. Your Python objects go on independently of each other after the `fork()` and do not share modifications to their state. The problem is that pre-fork opened files, pipes, and sockets will be shared, which is why you need the separate engines if you're using a connection pool.

Without knowing what your `init_db` does specifically, if the engines are being created after the `fork`, you should be fine - each process will have its own open sockets. It might be cleaner to move your `import` after the `fork` as well to be clear about your intent.

Comment: `init_db` calls the SQLAlchemy methods `create_engine`, `sessionmaker(bind=engine)`, `scoped_session()` on the result of the second call, then `create_all_tables()`. What if I call `init_db` in the parent process before the fork, and assign `engine` to the new engine returned by `init_db` in the child process? That's my actual use case. But doing this results in "psycopg2.OperationalError: SSL connection has been closed unexpectedly".

Comment: `create_engine` should be after the `fork`. I think your other model setup could be as well, but if there's a reason you need to set it up pre-fork you could leave the `bind` parameters off and then set them after creating the engine.